# Switch Buttons ON/OFF texts are not coming Android List view

Tags: android, uiswitch

I am trying build list view with some switch buttons.
On switch buttons instead of  ON/OFF texts, 0/1 states are coming on the switch.(As you see the switches in samsung devices->settings ex:wifi switch button).Other than list view i get proper switch buttons with OFF/ON texts.

```
<Switch
        android:id="@id/switch_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I am getting this problem only in Samsung devices, in nexus devices they switch buttons are fine.
What is the way to get ON/OFF texts in switch buttons when they are list view?

Comment: Show us the XML where you have the switch button setup. Are you setting textOn and textOff properly?

Comment: add your code if any
or share image what actually do you want?

Comment: Above switch code comes with OFF and ON texts in simple UI.But in listview switch button comes with 0 and 1 states.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to force the text to be displayed:

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:textOff="OFF" />
```